# How to prove that a metric space is a normed space?

Tags: functional-analysis

For example: Let's say that we have defined $\varrho(x,y)=|x^3-y^3|$. How to prove the metric space $\varrho$ is also a normed vector space?

Definition of normed vector space: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normed_vector_space

Definition of metric space:
A set $X$ is called a metric space, if $\forall x,y\in X \ : \ \varrho(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}$ so that:
$1. \ \varrho(x,y)=0 \Leftrightarrow x=y$

$2. \ \varrho(x,y)=\varrho(y,x)$

$3. \ \varrho(x,y)\leq\varrho(x,z)+\varrho(z,y)$

Comment: On what space is your "metric" defined? If it's defined on the complex numbers, it isn't even a metric...

Comment: A "normed space" that is also a linear space?  Or do you mean some other definition of "normed space"?  If so, we cannot answer unless we know that definition.

Comment: As a rule, the distance must satisfy the properties of a norm, in particular it must be homogeneous.

Comment: I added definitions to the question

Comment: To show its a normed vector space, just check if the metric satisfies the norm axioms. @5xum, I am trying to find an example to show that if its defined on the complex, its not a metric. Do you have a quick counter example?

Comment: @TylerHilton The distance between $e^{\frac{2\pi i}{3}}$ and $e^{\frac{4\pi i}{3}}$ is $0$, but the two numbers are not equal. Therefore, not a metric because the first axiom is broken.

Answer (score 1):

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space. By the definition $X$ is a set with no special structure on it. But for the metric $d$ to be induced by a norm with

$$d(x,y)=||x-y||$$
we have two necessary conditions:

1) $d(x+a,y+a)=d(x,y)$

2) $d(\alpha x,\alpha y)=|\alpha|d(x,y)$

For example the discrete metric space is not a normed space as its metric does not satisfy the above conditions.
Can you check these conditions for the given metric?